# Stylesheets and images not reflecting while rendering ejs file

Tags: html, node.js, express, directory, ejs

I am working on a website and while rendering an ejs file (index.ejs), only the html part is shown meanwhile the stylesheets and fonts and images are not shown.

The code to link the stylesheets is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PUBG Tournaments by Regal Gaming</title>
    <!-- load stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:100,300,400">
    <!-- Google web font "Open Sans" -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <!-- Magnific pop up style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo-style.css">
```

I am using a template and i have kept the structure of the directory the same.
Meaning, the css, js, img and the fonts folder are in the same directory as the index.ejs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

Rendering the static files into an ejs template requires the files to be in public directory.
Added this to the server file:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```